# I am getting assertion error in this following chai expect

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

So I am trying to add two datatypes and see what they result in. For example I want 1 + 1 to give me 2 and 1 + "one" to give me "1one". This is my functions.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    addingTwoDataTypes(one, two) {
        return (one + two);
    }
};
```

and this is my test file:

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var functions = require("../lib/functions")

describe("addingTwoDataTypes()", function () {
    it("should return the sum of two numbers", function() {
      var results = functions.addingTwoDataTypes(2 + 2);
      expect(results).to.equal(4);
    });
});
```

after running the test i get the following error:

```
addingTwoDataTypes()
    1) should return the sum of two numbers


  0 passing (12ms)
  1 failing

  1) addingTwoDataTypes()
       should return the sum of two numbers:

      AssertionError: expected NaN to equal 4
      + expected - actual

      -NaN
      +4

      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:7:26)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling a function,
`var results = functions.addingTwoDataTypes(2 + 2);`
 SHould be `(2,2)` not `(2 + 2)`.
Youre sending `(4, undefined)` to your function

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, silly mistake.

wrong:

```
var results = functions.addingTwoDataTypes(2 + 2);
```

correct:

```
var results = functions.addingTwoDataTypes(2, 2);
```